c# WPF display Listbox with 3 columns in each row
I would like to display three columns in each row with some images and a text. But whatever i try i cannot get the ListBox to display the Items horizontaly. Only the Stackpanel inside the Listbox itself.
<ListBox Name="lsbox" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Cards}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Margin="3" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Image Width="200" Height="300" Margin="100" Source="{Binding Path}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <UniformGrid Columns="3"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

Images are displayed below each other
I previously was able to get the images to display next to each other like this:
<ListBox Name="lsbox" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Grid.Row="1">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Columns="3"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <Image Source="33bfedbf836836cd81108e1e3e57a8e1.jpg"/>
                <Image Source="33bfedbf836836cd81108e1e3e57a8e1.jpg"/>
                <Image Source="33bfedbf836836cd81108e1e3e57a8e1.jpg"/>
            </ListBox>

3 Images are displayed horizontaly in each row
But like this I could only set the image source manually and not with Bindings to set the Items or Image Source.
I just started with wpf so i am really at my limits here.
Best Regards
Robin

You could try the SharedSizeGroup of grids in each row? And what about a ListView?

I think you should be able to set the ControlTemplate to have a suitable StackPanel and then the controls would be created in it

Configure the item panel the same way as before, then remove the <UniformGrid /> from inside the data template:
<ListBox Name="lsbox" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Cards}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="3"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Margin="3" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Image Width="200" Height="300" Margin="100" Source="{Binding Path}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

